# How to call a function in a c++ object file from java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have existing cpp files from a project which I would like to use it for my application which is in Java. I cannot change the cpp files. How can I call the functions from Java?

I'm working in Windows 10 using JavaFX for my application. I've seen some articles about JNI but none seem to solve my issue.

Comment: You are on the right track with JNI: Create Java classes with `native` methods, then create a C++ library that provides implementations for these methods (that then call into your original C++ library). If the types involved are not too hairy you may be able to generate most of the wrapper library using SWIG.

Comment: Not related but if we use JNI, can we still use the application for multiple platforms?

Comment: A common trick is to package one variant of the library per platform into your JAR and at run-time extract the appropriate one to a file and call `loadLibrary` on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If JNI or swig is not desired or seems too low level,

A really **blunt approach** is to wrap the .cpp in c/c++ program and built an .exe that dumps to stdout/file. Then execute that in java via an external shell command.

Another good alternative is

[Apache thrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift)

This basicly handles everything and goes everywhere so to speak (works by auto-generating code to target languages) and it is one I usually recommend in RPC situations. However there could be more setup cost involved (in the end, depends on your actual needs) - also since you need to host the .cpp in a service, in your case, locally.

Answer (score 2):

If you package your library inside a shared object or a dll, you can also use JNA: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna or https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md

For example, you already have mapping to Windows API.
Another example is a mapping of mediainfo in Java: https://github.com/andersonkyle/mediainfo-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apothem/mediainfo/api/MediaInfo.java

Note that, as far as I understand it, this is based on JNI: it simplify the process since you mostly have to only declare interface on Java side and call appropriate method.